# Get sub array from sub array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a data structure like that:

```
Array(
    [494] => Array(
        [meta_key] => course_494_access_from
        [expires_in] => 95
    ),
    [498] => Array(
        [meta_key] => course_498_access_from
        [expires_in] => 122
    ),
    [502] => Array(
        [meta_key] => course_502_access_from
        [expires_in] => 30
    ),
    [506] => Array(
        [meta_key] => course_506_access_from
        [expires_in] => 365
    )
)
```

and I like to ask, if there is a way to get the expires_in value by searching the `course_502_access_from`

So, in example, I like to know if there is a way to perform an array search in the given structure, by usign the term `course_502_access_from` and then get the value `30` that corresponds to sub array key `expires_in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case when there are multiple occurences of searching string (`'course_502_access_from'`) you may use `array_filter` with `array_map`.
Somehow like this:

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($v) {
        return $v['expires_in'];
    },
    array_filter($array, function ($v) {
        return $v['meta_key'] == 'course_502_access_from';
    }
);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just loop in array and use [**`in_array()`**](https://www.php.net/in_array) function to find your match value

```
foreach($array as $key => $data)
{
    if(in_array("course_502_access_from",$data))
    {
        echo $array[$key]['expires_in'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Working sample [**here**](http://codepad.org/6TY5bciY)

Comment: Adding a `break;` in the `if` would avoid useless loops as it appears that there is no twice the same `course_502_access_from` in the array

Answer (score 1):

If the structure never changes and stays that way, its pretty easy, yes:

```
foreach($your_array as $a) {
    if($a["meta_key"] === "course_502_access_from") {
        return $a["expires_in"];
    }
}
```

If it does and you get multiple layers ... well, then things start to become complicated. You could create a function and use it recursive ... but that would require more than just these 5 lines of code.